# Is it possible to install an newer version of android for an old android device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, rom, lenovo

I've got a phone with Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean installed on it, and it doesn't have a 'Software update' button. Is it possible at all to somehow install a newer version of Android on this device?

I also looked at a possibility to install CyanogenMod on this phone, but it doesn't have my phone in the list on http://get.cm. The model is the Lenovo A830, so it's not a conventional phone. Is it possible to install some kind of 'generic' version of Android on it?

Alternatively, can I install a mod that uses a more recent Android version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to install newer version of android on an old device but if any custom ROM exist for that device.
Matter of fact Cyanogen is one of popular custom distribution of android also there are many custom distributions for android that may support your device.
My advice to you is checking xda developers forums to find any possible ROMS for your device.
[XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/)

Comment: But could I take for example a ROM for a Lenovo A850 and put it in my A830? Or a Motorola (which got acquired by Lenovo in 2014) ROM work? Or would neither of those work?

Comment: @Joeytje50 It's not like windows, Generally you can't but there are minor exceptions for devices with very similar hardware specs.

Comment: On the XDA developers site, the closest match for Lenovo A830 is the A850. So would it break my phone if I tried installing that, or would I then be able to revert to the original state?

Comment: Usually developers in XDA provide enough information to clarify if that ROM could be used on any other devices, Anyway based on GSMARENA devices you mentioned have different chipset so that means I don't think you can cross-flash their ROMs on each other.

Comment: How can I find a device which would work? Is any device with a "Mediatek MT6589" chipset right for my phone?

Comment: You can't just find a compatible ROM for your device chipset and using that on your device (We can assume ROMs are designed for a particular device), I think just by googling 'Lenovo A830 custom rom' you can find your answer, Good Luck!

Comment: I already tried that, and I couldn't find any ROMs with Android 4.4 or higher for A830. So could I try installing a ROM for a different device with the same chipset, or would that completely destroy my device?

Comment: I don't recommend you to do that, There is high risk of hard brick!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44045/discussion-between-yamin-and-joeytje50).